# How to confirm a rumour without being disrespectful?

Tags: communication, ethics

I recently received a rumour: A told B who told C who told D who told me about a very serious piece of information (and one that could lead to serious issues). I would like to ask A (by e-mail, since I don't have contact with this person) directly about that by writing. However it seems that nobody from the chain is willing to put in writing what they are saying (to avoid being responsible, I believe) and I was once (in another occasion with another coworker) literally yelled upon for mentioning that I wanted to confirm with the source.

I want to ask A to confirm this, however I'm concerned that A could snitch me to B, C or D. How could I confirm this without being regarded as disrespectful or unprofessional?

Comment: How do you know that A told B who told C who told D? Do you have confirmation of the gossip chain all the way back to A?

Comment: I understand your need to keep the details as vague and ambiguous as possible. However, could you provide us with at least these two details: (1) What is your position in the company with respect to A, B, C, D? Specifically are you the manager of one or more of them, or possibly a subordinate to one of them? (2) Are you in a position to do directly influence anything to "fix" this serious problem?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace, by the way, Gabriel Diego. I think this was a good first question here, given the constraints I imagine you have about sharing more details.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri D told me that C had a meeting with B and the information comes from A.

Comment: @MaskedMan I'm not superior to A or B, but C and D are my superiors. If something goes wrong, there is nothing that I could do about that (may be go to jail).

Comment: Would _you_ be going to jail or would A be going to jail? And whose fault would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you haven't given many specifics, but I would say that if the information is something that is potentially of business importance to the organization (or relates to a safety, legal or ethical issue), then I would strongly consider bringing it to the attention of someone that is approachable *and* more senior than either A, B, C or D. This could possibly be your Manager, HR Manager, or perhaps the head of your division (depending on your position and who you have a good relationship with). They can then investigate, without anyone being able to trace it back to you.

If the information is of business importance, then it strikes me as somewhat unprofessional of A, B, C and D that they do not want to take responsibility and confirm it.

It may be best to discuss with your Manager first, so they don't feel like you are going over their head. You may even find that the higher-ups in your business will appreciate that you've brought it to their attention and respect you more for it.

Answer (score 7):

> I recently confronted a situation where A told B who told C who told D who told me about a very serious piece of information (and one that if there is the slightest deviation could lead to serious issues), so I would like to ask A (by e-mail, since I don't have contact with this person) directly about that by writing.

Who told who is irrelevant - by the time there's that many people in the "chain", it's basically an office rumour, and you should treat it as such. If you're in a position of *authority* over A, and you feel you need to get to the bottom of it, then just ask A directly. This can be an "Is it true that" type question, you certainly don't need to state where you got the information.

Based on A's reaction you can then drop it, escalate it, or whatever else is appropriate.

If you're *not* senior to A, then you shouldn't do anything to stir the pot. Treat it as an office rumour, take it with a pinch of salt, and don't get involved.

Comment: It is hard treat something as a rumor when you are personally involved with the subject and there would be personal consequences if there is any mistake on that.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have a good working relationship with my line managers (next 2 levels). If I come about to know some piece of information  which is unclear how to handle it, I ask the line manager by phone. This happens maybe every two years or so.

If I do decide to handle something like this myself, I typically ask the person who should be asked instead of the person who supposedly told about it about the information in question in a way which does not suggest the answer, e.g. I i heard about liquidity problems at a customer, i would send an email to the accounting department where I ask about the order/billing status for the projects in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to your situation with two actions: (1) report what you have been told to an appropriate senior authority, and (2) investigate the rumor chain yourself.

Reporting to authority requires that there is a senior authority that you trust, and that would not be obligated to do something that will destroy your livelihood. In other words, you could report to a C-level manager or board member, but perhaps not to the SEC or the police.

If you report upward, you will need to include everything you were told, including who told you and who he says told him. Before you do this, it is only fair to tell D what you are about to do. This gives him some warning, and allows you to find out if D will back you up or deny what he said.

If you investigate the rumor chain, you should start by telling D that you intend to confirm his story with C. Then talk to C and ask him if the information is true.

If he validates the information, and verifies that he got it from B, the tell him that you intend to confirm his story with B. Then talk to B and ask him if the information is true.

As you attempt to walk the rumor back to its source, a couple of things may happen. You may run into a link that declines to validate. This means that, as far as you are concerned, somebody is not telling the truth, and you are justified in trying to find out who that is.

Or, you may find the information has been altered, adjusted, or adulterated in the retelling. As you get closer to the true source, you also get a more accurate version of the information.

In any case, since it is perfectly legitimate and reasonable for you to want to know the truth, it is perfectly legitimate and reasonable for you to track down the source, and it is completely illegitimate and unreasonable for anyone to expect you to simply take their word on such an important subject.

Now, since it is legitimate for you to track down the source, you are not telling D anything surprising or unreasonable when you say you are going to talk to C. Same goes for every link in the chain. No one has any cause to feel insulted by your actions.

You would even be acting ethically to go directly to A for confirmation, but this would be discourteous to B, D, and D. It is much better to let everyone know that you do not think that information of this importance should be passed around in a game of whispers.

Also note that reporting upward and walking back the rumor are not mutually exclusive; you can do both, possibly in either order.